# Advanced Discord Ban Command

Tags: discord.py, nextcord

i need a ban command that bans a member and than dms the banned member to inform them about it and when it happened.
I have a few problems:

1. What if the user's dms are closed?
2. It is not dming the banned member.
3. Also includes a perm ban like `!Ban

If anyone can help me out that will be great and i will greatly appricate it.
Thanks!

Comment: It seems you can't check permissions from DMs please see [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=dmchannel#discord.DMChannel.permissions_for).
I recommend you to try/catch when you're sending your message to the DMs user.

Comment: It is actually possible to [check whether a bot can DM a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70660854/how-to-check-if-a-bot-can-dm-a-user/70780850#70780850).

Comment: Also, @Ryzer please see [ask]. Stack Overflow is for specific questions, but this question asks multiple questions in one. Please narrow your question down to a specific programming question so that answerers can assist you more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Like you want, this is example of simple `ban` member for `discord.py`

```
@client.command()
async def ban(ctx, member:discord.Member, *, reason=None)
    await member.ban
    await member.send(f"You've been banned by {ctx.author}\nReason = {reason}")
```

If you looking for `.cogs` version

```
@commands.command()
async def ban(self, ctx, member:discord.Member, *, reason = None)
    await member.ban
    await member.send(f"You've been banned by {ctx.author}\nReason = {reason}") ##this send message by DMs for banned member to tell him/her why getting banned
```

If you using discord-py-slash-command you can create new question

Answer (score -1):

for the 1:

> ```
> try:
>      await user.send("msg")
> except discord.errors.Forbidden:
>      code here
> ```

I don't know if this can help you